# I have a column CHANGE_DATE in my table which is a date with timestamp, how can I fetch rows where CHANGE_DATE is equal to yesterdays date

Tags: sql, database, oracle, spring-data-jpa

I have a CHANGE_DATE column ( 2019-06-06T18:30:00.000+00:00") in a table USER_DETAILS, I have to fetch rows where CHANGE_DATE is yesterdays date. Can you please help me with the SQL query

Comment: Does this column datatype is VARCHAR?

Comment: Its datatype is DATE

Comment: Its oracle database not MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from USER_DETAILS where date(CHANGE_DATE)=date_add(current_date,interval -1 day);
```